# My new button is in the wrong place

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

Initially, I was trying to have the "Add to Cart" button change to "Make an Inquiry" based on the condition of availability and whether there was a price inputted, or not. I kind of got the availability part, but still cant get the price part. Also my new button is not appearing in the same place as the "add to cart" button. What am I doing wrong?

Also the tab link isn't working the way i need it to. I linked it to a new question because... well you'll see if you [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833808/how-do-i-link-my-add-to-cart-button-to-a-specific-on-page-tab-and-scroll-to-it).

Also how do i constrain the size of both buttons to a maximum width.
Below is what i have thus far.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','replace_add_to_cart');
    function replace_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

        if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ){
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','consult_bezambar_expert', 30 );

    function consult_bezambar_expert() {
    global $product;

        echo '<form action="' . esc_url($product->get_permalink( "#tab- reviews" )) . '" method="get">
            <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Consult Bez Ambar Expert</button>
            </form>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted your CSS styles and a screenshot.

Comment: Ok, So there is alot of css, but I kind of see my problem. [The original](http://www.diamondloop.co/product/diamond-engagement-ring-with-floating-center-cleo-copy/) "add to cart" button is in the .summary-container within my css. That holds most the the product information and I centered it all. When I created the [new](http://www.diamondloop.co/product/1-carat-princess-cut-engagement-ring-ring-fire/) "add to cart/ Consult expert" button, it appears outside of the container and seems to ignore the hook hierarchy.

Comment: Im kind of lost on how to add it back to the container, or why its even out of it in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I put the links up. [Here](http://www.diamondloop.co/product/diamond-engagement-ring-with-floating-center-cleo-copy/) is where the button should be, and [here](http://www.diamondloop.co/product/1-carat-princess-cut-engagement-ring-ring-fire/) is where it is at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was a pretty simple oversight actually. I forgot the the number after the add or remove action represents priority and by putting the same priority I was messing things up. So i just removed the priority to the remove add to cart action.

So my code now looks like this

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
global $product;

    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','consult_bezambar_expert', 30 );

function consult_bezambar_expert() {
global $product;

    echo '<form action="' . esc_url($product->get_permalink( "#tab- reviews" )) . '" method="get">
        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Consult Bez Ambar Expert</button>
        </form>';
        }
    }
}
```